# JQuery Select Multiple Divs with Dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

Long time browser, first time poster.

What I'd like to do is have a user select the number of weeks to display in a dropdown menu, and then reveal that many divs. Right now I have it setup where I can reveal one div or all, but I'd like to do it for the previous divs.

Right now I have:

```
<SELECT name="number_of_weeks" id="number_of_weeks">
<OPTION value = "week1">1</OPTION>
<OPTION value = "week2">2</OPTION>
<OPTION value = "week3">3</OPTION>
</SELECT>

<div id = "week1" class = "weekmenu">
Week 1 </br>
</div>
<div id = "week2" class = "weekmenu">
Week 2 </br>
</div>
<div id = "week3" class = "weekmenu">
Week 3 </br>
</div>
```

And for the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.weekmenu').hide();
        $('#week1').show();
        $('#number_of_weeks').change(function () {
            $('.weekmenu').hide();
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
```

The output should be something like this: If week1 is selected only the week1 div is shown. If week 2 is selected, both the week1 and week2 divs are shown. If week 3 is selected the week1, week2, and week3 divs are shown.

I've been banging my head over this...I tried creating some nested divs but it didn't work out quite right. I also tried to give multiple divs their own classes, and then try to show those.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/meRcr/21/

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO, officially. =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the last line of jQuery to:

```
  $('#' + $(this).val()).prevUntil('select').addBack().show();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q9yKN/)**

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.weekmenu').hide();
    $('#week1').show();
    $('#number_of_weeks').change(function () {
        $('.weekmenu').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).prevUntil('select').addBack().show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

`$('#' + $(this).val()).prevAll('.weekmenu').andSelf().show();` is the key.

[.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) will get you all the preceding siblings matching the selector `.weekmenu` and then include itself too using `andSelf()` to the collection.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.weekmenu').hide();
    $('#week1').show();
    $('#number_of_weeks').change(function () {
        $('.weekmenu').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).prevAll('.weekmenu').andSelf().show();
    });
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybsRv/)

Comment: This also works wonders! I wish I could give two right answers! Maybe this is more correct because it would fit more folk's situations..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, I didn't test it but I think it works:)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.weekmenu').hide();
    $('#week1').show();
    $('#number_of_weeks').change(function () {
        $('.weekmenu').hide();

        var weekNumbers = $(this).val();
        for(var i = 1; i<= weekNumbers; i++) {
            $('#week' + i).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a cascading approach. Have a child-parent relationship through `data-*` attributes. On each div, have its previous divs id in the attribute. `data-parentid="2"`. Then you can just keep chaining your functionality until you get to a div with no parentid. You can change your layout anyway you choose and this relationship will be intact.